# xamarin forms Android.Support.v4 23.3.0.0 missing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

On adding a new package to my Xamarin forms solution, Xamarin informs me that I'm missing my android.support.v4 package, as well as the other 6 dependent packages.

It seems that when installing a nuget package, the installer deletes then re-installs the other packages. The android support packages seem to point to a different version than before. This comes from the package not being able to fully download because the folder file path is too long, then instructs me to download and install manually. After installing manually, I'm still getting error that I'm missing the Android.Support.v4 packages.

Comment: Please try removing and reinstalling only Xamarin.Forms - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/#Error_Unable_to_find_a_version_of_Xamarin.Forms_compatible_with...

Answer (score 0):

So the error was one of the files for the android.support package path was too long and could not unzip its contents. I did the following steps

1. remove all files from the App_Data/Local/Android/ directory as well as the Android.cache folder
2. rebuild solution
3. another error includes a link with the ziped file that could not automatically be installed. download that file and place the file as close as possible to the designated directory given.
4. extract all to the designated directory given in the original error (should be Android.support.(something)/ content. I had to make a content folder here before hand.
5. run this command in the nugat package manager console: 
   update-package -reinstall -ignoreDependencies
6. rebuild solution again

I had tried countless possible solutions online and none worked .this worked for me with Android support v4 23.3.0.0